# C++ Console cursor visibility change not working in some cases

Tags: c++

I trying to make a menu in which the user can browse the options with the arrow keys and select one with enter. I made the following function in order to hide the blinking cursor:

```
void ConsoleCursorVisibility(bool vis){
    HANDLE curs=GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO cci;
    GetConsoleCursorInfo(curs,&cci);
    cci.bVisible=vis;
    SetConsoleCursorInfo(curs,&cci);
}
```

Here is the menu function:

```
int optsel(string word[],int n){
    ConsoleCursorVisibility(false);
    char key;
    int setcol[n],opt=1;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        setcol[i]=7;
    }
    setcol[0]=116;
    while(true){
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            getoptxy(20,26+i);
            color(setcol[i]);
            cout<<i+1<<". "<<word[i];
        }
        key=_getch();
        if(key==72&&opt>1){
            opt--;
        }
        if(key==80&&opt<n){
            opt++;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            setcol[i]=7;
        }
        setcol[opt-1]=116;
        if(key=='\r'){
            break;
        }
    }
```

This seems to work only half of the time though because in this function it doesn't do anything:

```
void admintools(HOTELS &hotel){
    drawmenu(1);
    string prompt[5]={"Add/Remove hotels","User info","Exit"};
    int opt=optsel(prompt,3),optt;
    //it continues onward, but I don't believe it is necessary to give the entire thing
}
```

I don't know if it's important, but optsel and admintools are in different files, which are part of a Code::Blocks project.

If anyone knows what causes the issue please help! I don't have almost any experience working with windows.h, so I don't understand everything very well.

I tried moving the `ConsoleCursorVisibility(false)` to multiple different places within the optsel function, tried changing the cursor visibility before I the optsel. I don't have any more ideas what I can do.